# Display nice error message when there is something wrong after ajax request jqgrid

Tags: jqgrid, callback

I delete rows with this function:

```
function deleteRow(){
 rows = jQuery("#category_grid").getGridParam('selarrrow');
 if( rows.length>0){
  jQuery('#category_grid').delGridRow(rows,{
   msg:'Verwijderen geselecteerde rijen?'   
  });
 }else{
  alert("Selecteer eerst een rij om te verwijderen!"); 
 }
}
```

but when it's fails in my php, server side and a exception is thrown. The errormessage looks not nice. How can i show errotext in the dialog box? or catch an error message after an ajax call?

At the moment the error message looks like: error Status: 'CDbException'. Error code: 500

When i googled i found a event of the delGridRow function called errorTextFormat. Is this the event where i'm looking for? Can someone please give me an example of the implementation of this event?

greetings

niels

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second parameter of `delGridRow` is an object with options, so you can do like following

```
jQuery('#category_grid').delGridRow(rows,{
    errorTextFormat: function (data) {
        if (data.responseText.substr(0, 6) == "<html ") {
            return jQuery(data.responseText).html();
        }
        else {
            return data.responseText;
            // or
            // return "Status: '" + data.statusText + "'. Error code: " +data.status;
        }
    }
});
```

The text `retText`, which you give back by `errorTextFormat` function will be placed in the corresponding `div` of the error message with respect of `jQuery.html(retText)` code inside of `delGridRow` function.

By the way I don't call `delGridRow` function directly. Instead of that if I add the navigation bar to the jqGrid with respect of  `navGrid` function, I gives my `errorTextFormat` function as a parameter to standard "Delete button". To be exact I do this with respect of `$.jgrid.del`:

```
jQuery.extend(jQuery.jgrid.del, {
    ajaxDelOptions: { contentType: "application/json" },
    mtype: "DELETE",
    reloadAfterSubmit: false,
    jqModal: false,
    serializeDelData: function (postdata) {
        return "";
    },
    errorTextFormat: function (data) {
        if (data.responseText.substr(0, 6) == "<html ") {
            return jQuery(data.responseText).html();
        }
        else {
            return "Status: '" + data.statusText + "'. Error code: " + data.status;
        }
    }
});
```

(the real code of my `errorTextFormat` looks like a little more complex, but the idea of usage is the same).

Comment: Thank you Oleg, I solved my issue with this answer on "errorTextFormat"