# JqGrid forms server validations and custom error messages

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jqgrid

I have editable grid with toolbar that has buttons for editting adding and deleting records.

1. I would like to use server side validations from my asp.mvc to display validation messages on jqgrid edit form. (is this posible?)
2. I would like to overide message (Internal server Error ...) on edit form when exception occurs in the application. (this should be possible but I just cant figure out how to do this, perhaps using `errorTextFormat`, but how?  )

Can someone provide example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are right that [errorTextFormat](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing#events) is the correct way to get server response in case of HTTP errors and display the corresponding error message.

First of all your server have to return response with an [HTTP error code](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.4) in the HTTP header. Then you should define your implementation of the [errorTextFormat](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing#events) event handle either as a part of `prmEdit`, `prmAdd`, `prmDel` parameters of the [navGrid](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:navigator#definition) or you can overwrite jqGrid default settings (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5032327/jqgrid-navigator-how-to-specyfy-settings-globally/5032879#5032879)). I personally prefer to set [errorTextFormat](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing#events) by modifying of `jQuery.jgrid.edit` and `jQuery.jgrid.del`. An example of the corresponding code you can find in the following [old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2849189/display-nice-error-message-when-there-is-something-wrong-after-ajax-request-jqgri/2850524#2850524).

The exact code of [errorTextFormat](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing#events) function should **depend on the format of the server response**. I use ASP.NET MVC with WFC inside of the site and the server can return either JSON encoded string response (if the error come from `throw new WebFaultException<string> ("my error text", statusCode);` which I thrown explicitly) or sometime HTML response. In my implementation of [errorTextFormat](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing#events) I test which kind of error response I received and convert the server response. Here is the code fragment:

```
my.errorTextFormat = function (data) {
    var str = data.responseText.substr(0, 1);
    var str1 = data.responseText.substr(0, 6).toLowerCase();
    if (str === '"') {
        var errorDetail = jQuery.parseJSON(data.responseText);
        var s = "Fehler: '";
        s += data.statusText;
        s += "'. Details: ";
        s += errorDetail;
        return s;
    }
    else if (str1 === "<html " || str1 == "<html>" ||
             data.responseText.substr(0, 169) === '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>\r\n<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">\r\n<html ') {
        var bodyHtml = /<body.*?>([\s\S]*)<\/body>/.exec(data.responseText)[1];
        return bodyHtml; //bodyContents1;
    }
    else {
        var res = "Status: '";
        res += data.statusText;
        res += "'. Felhercode: ";
        res += data.status;
        return res;
    }
};
jQuery.extend(jQuery.jgrid.edit, {
    ...
    errorTextFormat: my.errorTextFormat
});
jQuery.extend(jQuery.jgrid.del, {
    ...
    errorTextFormat: Testportal.errorTextFormat
});
```

The code is not perfect, but you can use it to create your own one.

Comment: this is not working for me. My mvc controller is returning 500 error and I have used you above code on edit and that event is never fired.

Comment: @aman: Which code exactly you use? Which **version** of jqGrid you use and from which **fork** of jqGrid? The answer is very old and not full (for example, `var my = {};` isn't exist as the first statement and `Testportal.errorTextFormat` should be replaced to `my.errorTextFormat` of cause). More recent versions of jqGrid contains *localized* messages only and one have to replace `$.jgrid.edit` and `$.jgrid.del` to, for example, `$.jgrid.locales["en-US"].edit` and `$.jgrid.locales["en-US"].del`

Comment: actually I had raised a question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48524588/jqgrid-show-custom-message-on-form-field . And while searching came on this answer. Can you see my post at above link and see what could be a solution. Thanks