# jqGrid Ajax validation inside beforeSubmit

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have a jqGrid form for creating new users and what i want is to ensure that (among the other fields submitted by the form) the username does not already exist in the database.
So i created a beforeSubmit action, that is executed when the submit button is pressed but before the form is submitted.
I think the function works, because the code bellow always returns "User exists";

> beforeSubmit:function(postdata,formid) { return[false,"User exist"]; }

But when i try ti use the $.get to make an ajax request to the server in order to see if the username already exists, i always get a `k is undefined` error. This is the code the produces the error

> beforeSubmit:function(postdata,formid) {
>
> $.get("project-management?r=Users/usernameExists&tmpl=json&username="
>   + postdata.username, function(data) {
>    return[false,"Exists"];
>   }); }

I know that this is not a real validation but shouldn't produce the same result as the first script?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all I explain why you code don't work like you expect.

The method `$.get` works *asynchronous*. So

- your function `beforeSubmit` first start `$.get`
- then it returns `undefined` value bacause the body of the `beforeSubmit` function will be finished.
- Then after the asynchronous `$.get` request will get response from the server the `function(data) {` callback will be called (it's `success` callback).
- Your `success` callback return the value `return[false,"Exists"];` *from the callback*. The `$.get` don't  analyse any return value from the `success` callback so the array `[false,"Exists"]` will be discarded by `$.get`.

You can use `$.ajax` with `async: false` parameter instead of `$.get` as the workaround, but better is don't implement any `beforeSubmit` at all. If your server-based code find out that the user changes can't be saved or the input field contains some validation errors the server should just return response having some [error HTTP status code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes). The status code can be 400 or higher in case of validation errors - [the Client Error](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#4xx_Client_Error) or be 500 or higher in case of some other errors in processing the request on the server - [Server Error](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#5xx_Server_Error). The body of the server response can be HTML fragment of the message which jqGrid will display to the user.

You can customize the error message with respect of `errorTextFormat` callback. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5103844/315935) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6803206/315935) for additional information.

Comment: Thanks a lot Oleg. I used afterSubmit as i found in another post and it worked.