# How to handle server errors using jqgrid.net mvc in add or edit dialog

Tags: jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net, server-error

I am trialing jqgrid.net mvc and have noticed that any server error that happens in an add or edit popup dialog, ends up rendering the entire error page in the popup, which is not very pretty. Does anyone know if it is possible to handle this better and perhaps just put a brief message in the dialog instead, a bit like the way validation errors are handled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [errorTextFormat](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing#events). You can find some code fragments in [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5103844/315935) and in [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6803206/315935). I would recommend you to post HTTP error messages in JSON format. For example, in case of ASP.NET MVC you can use `HandleJsonExceptionAttribute` described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5501644/315935). It will convert all unhandled exceptions in the severe code to JSON response instead of default HTML response. You can easy modify the code to provide JSON response only if the client requested JSON format in the server response. The JSON response you can easy parse, but even in case of pure HTML response you get only the most important part of the response with respect of jQuery selectors and return from your implementation of the `errorTextFormat` callback.