# Error handling with afterSubmit is not showing on JqGrid's new model form

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, error-handling

I'm trying to show the server error to the user on JqGrid

here is my code:

```
function addRow() {
$("#updateList").jqGrid('editGridRow', "new", {
    editData: {
        Year: function () { return $('#year option:selected').val(); }
    }
     , afterSubmit: function (response, postdata) { return [false, "fdfdfdfd", "141"]; }
    , height: 400, width: 400, reloadAfterSubmit: true
});
```

}

I do get the json error from Server with StatusCode 500
I just wanted to test so I put

```
return [false, "fdfdfdfd", "141"]
```

But I always see the default error message

"error Status: 'error'. Error code: 500"

This is a 'new' row adding model form. not inline editing.

Thanks for any help...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are misunderstanding when `afterSubmit` can be used. The function could be helpful if your server framework produce *always* successful HTTP code and you can only place the information about the error inside of the body of the successful response.

In your case the server returns status code 500. So you should use [errorTextFormat](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing#events) instead. Try with

```
errorTextFormat: function (response) {
    return "ERROR: fdfdfdfd!";
}
```

More interesting implementation of `errorTextFormat` you can find for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5103844/315935). I recommend you additionally to read [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6803206/315935) and play with [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SimpleLocalGridWithMsgInEditForm.htm) from the answer.

Comment: Yes, I read [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6803206/315935) before & I got confused with the statement "It's important to know that afterSubmit will be called only if the server response contain error HTTP status code.".  I'm pretty sure that was a typo ;)

Anyhow, thanks for great answer.  I see all JqGrid questions.. you rock.

Comment: @SKCSKNathan001: Thanks! I fixed the typo from "contain" to "not contains". You are welcome!